# Is health related or health-related correct in speaking about health related issues?

Tags: hyphenation

Is health related or health-related correct?  For example, would one write health related issues or health-related issues and health related efforts or health-related efforts?

Answer (score 2):

If "health-related" comes before the word it modifies (in this case, "issues"), then it gets a hyphen because it's a compound of a noun ("health") and a participle ("related") modifying another noun ("issues"). If it comes after what it modifies (for example, "his absence was health related"), it doesn't need the hyphen.

Comment: I think you meant to type "in this case, 'issues'."

Comment: I'd use a hyphen in either case.  If you hate hyphens, make it “his absence was related to health”, which is less ‘headlinese’ anyway.